# How to receive a http post in Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

Function 1 sends a message body by HTTP post every 5 minutes.
In Data Factory I want to receive this message and pass this body to Function 2 as input.

{
"body": "run"
}

How can I receive this message in the Azure Data factory?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that Azure Data Factory is the right tool for this job?

Comment: @PeterBons I don't know and I will search about that and I ask is it possible? Also, I found this article : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/v1/data-factory-http-connector.md

Comment: You should just either call `Function 2` from `Function 1` directly or have `Function 1` output to something that can trigger `Funtion 2`, such as an Event Queue.

Comment: @iamdave If I call function 2 from function 1 directly, I need to run some other activity after function 2 as a pipeline(etc, copy function 2's output do database). I think in my scenario, I should find a solution for function 1 post a URL to the data factory, and after that the pipeline run.

Answer (score 3):

Okay first off, you can definitely trigger a pipeline execution in ADF via a REST API call and even pass parameters (such as body contents) to that pipeline.

Refer to this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run

I’m not at my computer right now, but I will give an example tomorrow. That being said, there are many ways to do what you want, within ADF and without ADF.

Here is an example of calling an Azure Data Factory Pipeline from an HTTP Triggered Azure Function. I apologize I am not fluent in C# so the code might look bad, but I have tested this and it works.

Here is the code I am using for the Azure function:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;


public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["PipelineName"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.PipelineName;

using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
//I Gave my Azure Function a system assigned Managed Identity, that way you can give RBAC roles for access to Management API and Azure Data Factory
//The below code gets the access token to be used in authenticating for the next API Call to ADF
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Secret", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSI_SECRET"));
var response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format("{0}/?resource={1}&api-version={2}", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSI_ENDPOINT"), "https://management.azure.com/", "2017-09-01"));
string msiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
dynamic msiResponseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(msiResponse);
//Access Token is saved below
string accessToken = msiResponseData?.access_token;
//return new OkObjectResult(accessToken);

using(var client1 = new HttpClient())
    {
    string uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/pipelines/ADFTestPipeline/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01";
    //string uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/[SubscriptionID]/resourceGroups/[ResourceGroupName]/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/[DataFactoryName]/pipelines/[PipelineName]/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01";
    string content = "{}";
        client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        //The below Posts to the ADF API using the authorization header and bearer token, in order to pass parameters to the ADF Pipeline, you can modify the content string variable above (json format)
        var response1 = await client1.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(content.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        var result = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return new OkObjectResult(result);


        //return new OkObjectResult(result);
    }
}
}
```

**In Order for this to work you need to make sure your Azure Function has a system assigned managed Identity, and then has access to your ADF to run a pipeline, and access to call the Azure Management API, these can both be assigned via RBAC**

SETTING SYSTEM ASSIGNED MANAGED IDENTITY ENABLED:

[image: Allowing System Assigned Managed Identity]

ROLES YOUR AZ FUNCTION NEEDS:

- Azure Data Factory Contributor
- API Management Service Contributor (might work with Operator, haven't tested)

**Proof that it works:**

Azure Function Output/Response:

[image: Test Run of Azure Function]

ADF Monitor Tab:

[image: ADF Monitoring Tab shows pipeline in progress]

I hope this helps and gives you an idea of how to make this work. Please accept as answer if it meets your needs and let me know if you need any more detail!

Comment: Thanks, the trigger of execution of ADF is when Function 1 post a message to Function 2. I will wait for your example.

Comment: Oh I understand now… I mean couldn’t you call the REST API within your azure function as the first step in the function then?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) supports a [limited set of triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers). An http trigger is not one of them.

I would suggest to have Function1 call Function2 directly. Then have Function2 store the data in a blob file.

After that you can use the [Storage event trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger) of ADF to run the pipeline:

> Storage event trigger runs a pipeline against events happening in a Storage account, such as the arrival of a file, or the deletion of a file in Azure Blob Storage account.

From there you can use the ADF pipeline to pick up the data and process it further in the pipeline.

Comment: Be aware that the storage event trigger is not 100% and operates on a best intentions model.  To reliably respond to *all* events, you would want to add a message to an event queue that actually triggers the processing, even if the processing involves a specifically created blob file.